# MVVM - Add one Column Dynamically in RadGridView

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik, radgridview

My application is in MVVM. I have a Telerik RadGridview where 2 columns are Databound and I have to generate third column dynamically with RowNumbers. 
 Here is my code. I am getting (collection) in the third (dynamically generated) column. The other 2 columns are fine. Please help me on this.

```js
XAML:

  < telerik: RadGridView Name = "TestGridView"
ItemsSource = "{Binding TestListView}"
AutoGenerateColumns = "False" >
  < telerik: RadGridView.Columns >
  < telerik: GridViewColumn Header = "RowCount" >
  < telerik: GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
  < DataTemplate >
  < StackPanel >
  < TextBlock Text = "{Binding TestRowNumber}" / >
  < /StackPanel>
                                     </DataTemplate >
  < /telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                             </telerik: GridViewColumn >
  < telerik: GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding = "{Binding FirstName}"
Header = " Name" / >
  < telerik: GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding = "{Binding Salary}"
Header = "Salary" / >
  < /telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
  </telerik: RadGridView >

  ViewModel:

  public void Testupdate() {
    RadObservableCollection < int > rno = new RadObservableCollection < int > ();
    for (int i = 1; i <= TestList.Count; i++) {
      rno.Add(i);
    }
    TestRowNumber = rno;
  }

private RadObservableCollection < int > _testRowNumber;
public RadObservableCollection < int > TestRowNumber {
  get {
    return _testRowNumber;
  }
  set {
    _testRowNumber = value;

    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

```
     }
```

Its showing correct count in the rno with items 1 to 6. But when displaying on the grid, its showing (collection). I am not able to trace where I am going wrong. Please correct me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The property named TestRowNumber defined as `RadObservableCollection<int>`
According to your code this collection is binded to the TestBlock's 'Text' property. During the binding collection's ToString() method get called and you get what you see. Assuming that FirstName and Salary are properties of Employee class you can do something like this:

```
class Employee
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}

class ViewModel
{
    private int imployeeIndex = 1;
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            AddNewEmployee("Name" + i, i * 1000);
    }

    public void AddNewEmployee(string name, double salary)
    {
        Employees.Add(new Employee { Index = imployeeIndex++, Name = name, Salary = salary });
    }
}

<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource= "{Binding Employees}" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" >
    <telerik:RadGridView.DataContext>
          <local:ViewModel/>
    </telerik:RadGridView.DataContext>
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewColumn Header = "RowCount" >
            <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Index}" />
                </DataTemplate >
            </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewColumn >
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding = "{Binding Name}" Header = "Name" />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding = "{Binding Salary}" Header = "Salary" />
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```